# Windows client can't communicate with server running in linux docker container

Tags: python, linux, docker, windows-10, docker-network

I am looking for some help with basic docker networking between a windows host and linux container.

As a docker newbie, I want my custom python client, running on the host machine, to be able to communicate with my custom python tcp server, running in a dev docker container.

When run exclusively on the windows 10 host, the client and sever can successfully connect and communicate.  When run exclusively on the linux container, the client and server can successfully connect and communicate.  The trouble occurs when I try to get the client on the windows 10 host server to communicate with the linux server in the container.  The client is able to connect to the exposed port, but it does not seem to be communicating with the server.  The logs on the containerized server do not show any connection being made when the client connects to the exposed port.

My docker setup is fairly basic:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8 AS base
RUN cp -f /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
COPY requirements.txt /tmp
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8888
CMD [ "python", "/opt/sog/server.py" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  sog:
    image: sog
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - ./sog/:/opt/sog
```

I've tried various tests to debug, such as:

1. Run client and server locally on the windows host

   - Connects and communicates
2. Run the client and server in the linux container

   - Connects and communicates
3. Run the client on windows and the server in the container, using 127.0.0.1:8888

   - Client connects to port, but fails to communicate
4. Run the client on windows and the server in the container, using docker IP:8888

   - Client can not connect to port
5. Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 -Port 8888

   - Succeeds
6. Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 -Port 8889

   - Fails, as expected (different port - testing the test)
7. telnet 127.0.0.1 8888

   - Seems to connect, but doesn't return or log anything useful.  Immediately exits.
8. telnet 127.0.0.1 8889

   - Fails to connect, as expected (different port - testing the test)
9. As per some web searches, I've also tried setting the port in docker compose to `0.0.0.0:8888:8888`

   - Client connects to port, but fails to communicate
10. I've also tried temporarily turning off my antivirus software in case it was blocking communication

    - Client connects to port, but fails to communicate
11. I've considered that a firewall might be running in the docker container, but I don't see any evidence of iptables being installed

Given that the client/server app appears to work in both environments, I think I can rule out my python code as the culprit.  That leaves me thinking that I am missing something with my docker setup, that there is something blocking the connectivity, or that there is something inherently broken with my windows to linux network connection.

Any solutions or tips on how to further debug this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have the python server listening on all interfaces? That is, do you bind to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Bingo!  The python server was listening on 127.0.0.1.  When I changed it to 0.0.0.0, everything worked as expected.  No changes were required to the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml.  Thanks, Karl.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14172230/karl)'s comment, the python server needed to be binded to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.  No changes were required to the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml.